# Consultar 2 tablas de 2 bases de datos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como puedo consultar una tabla de una base de datos y otra tabla de otra base de datos, en sql server

es decir necesito consultar la empresa de las 2 base de datos

lo estaba realizando de esta manera pero me saca error

Las bases de datos son: `Sk_BDDespachos` y `Sk_BDDespachosPruebas`
Las tablas son: `Sk_Empresa` y  `Sk_Empresa`
el campo de las tablas son: `Sk_Nombre_Empresa` y `Sk_Nombre_Empresa`

```
SELECT 
Sk_BDDespachos.Sk_Empresa.Sk_Nombre_Empresa,
Sk_BDDespachosPruebas.Sk_Empresa.Sk_Nombre_Empresa
FROM Sk_BDDespachos.Sk_Empresa , Sk_BDDespachosPruebas.Sk_Empresa;
```

Comment: podrias mostrar la estructura de la tabla con los campos ya que no se entiende bien cuales son los nombres.

Comment: Ya actualice la pregunta

Comment: Cual es el error que te arroja, los 2 servidores de datos están vinculadas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes intentarlo de esta forma

```
    SELECT A.Sk_Nombre_Empresa, B.Sk_Nombre_Empresa
    FROM Sk_BDDespachos.DBO.Sk_Empresa A
    INNER JOIN Sk_BDDespachosPruebas.DBO.Sk_Empresa B
    ON A.Sk_Nombre_Empresa = B.Sk_Nombre_Empresa
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
*
FROM Sk_BDDespachos.dbo.Sk_Empresa A 
INNER JOIN  Sk_BDDespachosPruebas.dbo.Sk_Empresa B
ON A.Sk_Empresa = B.Sk_Empresa;
```

Prueba Esto

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es consultar las empresas de ambas tablas podrias hacer algo como esto:

```
    SELECT  Sk_Nombre_Empresa
    FROM    Sk_BDDespachos.dbo.Sk_Empresa
    UNION
    SELECT  Sk_Nombre_Empresa 
    FROM    Sk_BDDespachosPruebas.dbo.Sk_Empresa
```

Ya que un inner join te mostraria solo las empresas que hacen match y una consulta como la que estabas haciendo te va a mostrar las empresas de ambas tablas relacionadas entre si.
No se realmente que es lo que esperas de tu consulta.